# Cocoa: No keyboard events will fire while dragging (NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, event-handling, nsrunloop

I am successfully able to react to keyboard events through my window controller's keyDown: method.
The problem arises while performing a mouse drag:
Keyboard events seem to be delayed and will only fire on mouse up.

To be clear, what I mean is:
• place a log statement in you window controller's keyDown: method
• launch your app, perform some drag operation (on a NSSlider for ex.)
• while maintaining the drag, press any key: nothing logs to the console.
• release drag : logs appear, yay…

The control i am dragging is a custom NSSlider.
I have implemented the dragging mechanism using a 'Mouse-Tracking Loop' Approach.
for what I understand, when dragging, NSApplication's main run loop mode is being switched to NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode, thus restricting incoming events.

So, i simply added NSKeyDownMask & NSKeyUpMask in my tracking loop and when encoutered, called self.nextResponder keyDown/up: method accordingly.
My problem is solved for this particular custom subclass.

But what about cocoa's native controls ? I can't code that exception...

I had hoped for NSEvent's "addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:" method
but alas, says doc : "will not be called for events that are consumed by nested event-tracking loops such as control tracking, menu tracking, or window dragging".

So, isn't there a straightforward solution to receive keyboard events regardless of the app's runloop mode ?

Comment: I have a similar problem in that timers don't seem to fire when I use the 'Mouse-Tracking Loop' Approach - no matter what run loop mode I add the timers to. Timers do fire when a top level menu is pulled down... - so any progress on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found in the documentation for the `NSEvent` class' `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`, this limitation is by design.

However, you can work around it by using the IOKit framework (specifically the IOHID portions) to receive low level device events/interrupts. I just had to do this recently for tracking some specific keypresses during mouse-drags.

The basic gist is to create an IOHID manager with `IOHIDManagerCreate()`, then add the type(s) of devices to the manager that it should "monitor" with `IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatchingMultiple()`, register a callback with the manager via `IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback()`, schedule the proper run-loop for the manager with `IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop()`, and finally open the manager with `IOHIDManagerOpen()`.

To get these low level events during mouse-drags, perform this setup in a separate thread. When scheduling the run-loop for the manager, use `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()` to get the run loop for the current thread, and call `CFRunLoopRun()` after `IOHIDManagerOpen()`.

[This guide from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html) can help you get started, along with [this Q&A here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190852/using-iohidmanager-to-get-modifier-key-events).

Comment: I had been banging my head against the wall trying to get IOHIDManager working with a fullscreen CGL application.  I didn't realize from all the examples that you had to provide a run loop...  and I didn't realize until I read your answer that the run loop should probably be on another thread.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Any suggestions how to implement it using Swift? I have a problem which may be solved by this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631958/nsdraggingsession-cancelation-detection