# NSDraggingSession cancelation detection

Tags: swift, cocoa

The question is simple - is it possible for the `NSDraggingSource` to detect cancelation of the dragging session? This should occur when hitting the Esc key while dragging. According to my research there is no difference between dropping the item over a non dragging destination object (or an object returning false `performDragOperation(_:)`) and canceling. And I need to differentiate these two and perform different actions from `NSDraggingSource` object.

Any suggestion are more than welcome as usual ;-)

Comment: It's a bit hacky but maybe you can use the current event.

Comment: Actually while dragging the `RunLoop` is in `EventTracking` mode. So all events are stored. There is no way to get the `keyDown` event, unless by creating an `IOHIDManager` and scheduling it in the `RunLoop`. Unfortunately the `IOKit` framework is barely exposed to Swift ....

Comment: Try [currentEvent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428668-currentevent) of `NSApplication`, in `draggingSession(_:endedAt:operation:)` its `type` is `LMouseUp` or `KeyDown`.

Comment: This is a very ... VERY clever suggestion. Initially I did not get what you mean. It is not hacky at all. This is the logical approach . And yes - it worked. Of course that `currentEvent` will be a `keyDown` event in case of cancelling with Esc - this is the only `keyDown` event consumed while dragging ;-).The only thing that I regret for is not being able to figure this out by myself. Please describe it as an answer so I can accept it.